# Networking KVM virtual machines to VLAN interface on host

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I have a VLAN interface (`enp98s0f0.4000`) set up on my KVM host, which is a Hetzner dedicated server. The VLAN is set up to route through a [Hetzner vSwitch](https://docs.hetzner.com/cloud/networks/connect-dedi-vswitch/), and I can ping out to Cloud instances sitting on the other side of the vSwitch (for the sake of example, I can ping to a Hetzner Cloud instance at `10.0.0.3` from the host just fine).

I'm trying to configure networking such that a VM running on the host can also access Hetzner Cloud instances via the same vSwitch, and I figure I'd need to do that through the VLAN interface I set up on the host previously. But no amount of networking configurations through `nmtui` and the `virt-manager` GUI have made this work - I have tried making bridges in `systemd-networkd` and configuring a virtual interface in `virt-manager` to connect through that bridge, but that hasn't worked, even when attempting to set up routes both on the host and inside the VM.

Please advise on the simplest configuration to allow this to work, or if it's even possible.